# How can I call a Rust function from assembly?

Tags: function, assembly, rust

I am looking for like C calling via function call [function]. I am linking asm and Rust in one binary via ld.

Answer (score 5):

If you know how to call a C function from assembly (I don't, offhand), then this will help you get a Rust function that can be called like a C function:

```
// foo.rs
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn increment(a: i32) -> i32 {
    a + 1
}
```

Compile it as a dynamic or static lib:

```
$ rustc --crate-type dylib foo.rs
$ nm libfoo.dylib  | grep increment
0000000000000c70 t __ZN9increment10__rust_abiE
0000000000000c30 T _increment
```

Now you have a library that can be called like a C library. You should read the entire [FFI Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ffi.htm) to better understand the tradeoffs and pitfalls of calling Rust from outside of Rust.